# Unity Rendering Pass Before Refraction not showing

Tags: unity-game-engine

In the documentation it states:

> Before Refraction: Draws the GameObject before the refraction pass. This means that HDRP includes this Material when it processes refraction. To expose this option, select Transparent from the Surface Type drop-down.

I have selected the Transparent option for surface type but the Before refraction rendering pass is not in the drop down list for rendering pass. How can I get it to be there? Are there some other option that might be disabling it?

Comment: Hey Tom, you might be better off posting this on the Game Development stack exchange found at https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/ in order to get an answer

Comment: Any option other than `None` in `Transparency Inputs`->`Refraction Model` will disable the Before refraction option. See [this](https://forum.unity.com/threads/hdrp-meterial-glass-pre-refraction-pass-porblem.871366/) forum post. "_...a material that has refraction (refraction model set to something else then "none") can not be in Rendering Pass : Before Refraction (obviously)._"

Comment: Which version of Unity are you using? and is your project working with HDRP or URP?